# Runnable JAR renders SWT Spinner differently

Tags: java, swt, spinner

I am developing a swt application which should run as runnable JAR. All logic is working perfectly but SWT Spinner is not rendered correctly. Other UI components displayed as expected.

Should look like this (Running within eclipse):

[image: When running with eclipse]

But looks like that (Running in shell with: java -jar app.jar):

[image]

Does anyone faced similiar problems?

Configuration: Linux Mint 64, org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.jar version 4.4

Comment: You should show us your code.

Comment: Looks like Eclipse forces Gtk2 whereas the jar runs at Gtk3

Comment: Are you setting the size of the `Spinner` manually btw?

Comment: Baz was right! The runnable jar is using Gtk3. I set a fixed width for the spinner so that in Gtk3 it was displayed as in the second picture. Thank you guys. 

For anybody whos interested, you can force eclipse to use gtk3 described here: 

[https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/how-to-tell-if-you-are-running-eclipse-on-gtk2-or-on-gtk3/]